# Sorl thumbnail not opening image in template (Django)

Tags: django, upload, django-templates, thumbnails, sorl-thumbnail

I've followed a tutorial to create a thumbnail for uploading and posting filecontent and images in a template. I'm using Django 1.6. With one version the of get_method() related to the thumbnail field the place for uploaded  image or text shows in the html one_labeling_index.html below but unopened and with the second version, sorl - thumbnail, it doesn't show anything at all after using the "Browse" - upload button.

in models.py

```
from sorl.thumbnail import get_thumbnail
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
# instance, is instance from django and filename is name of uploaded file
#  formats str to filename format str

def get_upload_file_name(instance,filename):
    return "uploaded_files/%s_%s" % (str(time()).replace('.', '_'), filename)

class Labeling(models.Model):

    sentence = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    current_count = models.IntegerField()
    label = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    # thumbnail field
    thumbnail = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name)


 def __unicode__(self):
        return self.sentence

class OneLabeling_Phrase(models.Model):

    sentence = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    label = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    thumbnail = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name)
```

in views.py

```
def LabelingIndex(request):
        labels = Labeling.objects.all()

        return render(request,"labeling_index.html", {"labels":labels})


def one_labeling(request,postID):

    one_labeling = Labeling.objects.get(id=postID)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LabelingForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            postonelabeling(request, one_labeling)

    else:
        form = LabelingForm()

    m = {"form":form, "one_labeling":one_labeling}
    m.update(csrf(request))

    return render_to_response('one_labeling_index.html', m)
```

in forms.py

```
class LabelingForm(forms.ModelForm):


    class Meta:
        model = Labeling
        fields = ('title', 'current_count', 'sentence', 'label', 'thumbnail')
```

in urls.py

```
   url(r'^labeling$', LabelingIndex),
   url(r'^labeling(?P<postID>\d+)$',one_labeling),
```

in html labeling_index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>


{% for one_labeling in labels %}

    <h2><a href="/labeling{{ one_labeling.id}}">{{ one_labeling.title }}</a></h2>

    <p>{{ one_labeling.sentence }}</p>
    <p>{{ one_labeling.label }}</p>

    {% for c in one_labeling.onelabeling_phrase.set_all %}

         <p>{{ one_labeling.sentence }}</p>
         <p>{{ one_labeling.label }}</p>
         <p>{{ one_labeling.thumbnail }}</p>





    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}


</body>
</html>
```

in one_labeling_index.html

```
{% load static %}
{% load thumbnail %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>





<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
<ul>
    {{ one_labeling.thumbnail}}


     {{form.as_ul}}


    <p><img src="{% get_static_prefix %}{{one_labeling.get_thumbnail}}" width="200"/></p>

      # with soal - thumbnail
    {% thumbnail item.image my_size_string crop="left" as im %}
       <img src="{{thumbnail.labeling}}"width="200">
    {% empty %}
    <p>No image</p>
    {% endthumbnail %}


</ul>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the place for uploaded image or text shows in the html one_labeling_index.html below but unopened

I'm not sure what this means, but I assume you mean the space is there but there's no image showing. In this case, this is happening because you've placed a `<img>` with a broken source. The rest isn't showing anything at all because the code is broken.

There are some elements missing here. For instance, I'm not sure where variable `item` is coming from? Regardless, you're using sorl-thumbnail wrong. [Take a look at the examples in the docs](http://sorl-thumbnail.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples.html#template-examples). Remember you have `thumbnail item.image AS im`, which means your image object is now referenced with 'im'. im has attributes url, width, height. So your code should be:

```
{% thumbnail one_labeling.thumbnail '200x200' crop="left" as im %}
   <img src="{{ im.url }}" width="{{ im.width }}" heigh="{{ im.height }}">
{% empty %}
   <p>No image</p>
{% endthumbnail %}
```

`get_thumbnail` is a method from sorl-thumbnail, not your model, so you can't say `{{ one_labeling.get_thumbnail }}` unless you actually created this method in the the Labeling model. If you want to set the sorl-thumbnail from the model:

```
from sorl.thumbnail import get_thumbnail

class Labeling(models.Model):
   pass

   def get_thumb(self):
        im = get_thumbnail(thumbnail, '200x200', crop='center', quality=99)
        return im.url # remember that sorl objects have url/width/height attributes
```

So, in your template you could have:

```
<img src="{{ one_labeling.get_thumb }}" />
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks,this solution  works fine except the "Browse" button with thumbnail only works for browsing so I tried to add a submit <input type="submit" value="Upload" /> but it doesn't connect with the thumbnail button, I tried changing from thumbnail = request.POST['thumbnail'] to thumbnail = request.POST.get('thumbnail',False) but I get TypeError "'thumbnail' is an invalid keyword argument for this function".

Comment: @user1749431 So you want the image to change when someone browses for a new one? Like a preview?

Comment: that would also be a solution, currently the previously uploaded file is showing from the one_labeling_index.html before pressing the browse button and the browse button displays the name of the new selected file but doesn't open it and the selected filename that is displayed disappears when the page is updated.

Comment: @user1749431 If I'm understanding the problem, I think you may need to use JS/AJAX there, to upload the image to the model first, and send back the url to replace what is currently showing. Take a look at something like [this](https://github.com/tstone/django-uploadify/wiki)